# Does each WITH query count as a separate command in a read-committed transaction?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

Suppose I have the following trivial code:

```sql
BEGIN;
WITH foo AS (SELECT * FROM t1),
     bar AS (SELECT * FROM t1)
SELECT * FROM foo, bar;
COMMIT;
```

The isolation level will be, [by default, `READ-COMMITTED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED). This of course means if you had two separate selects you could (in theory) have non-repeatable reads.

My question is: in the example code, do these two different selects count as a single read-committed command, or is each select on its own, making it possible for both to (in theory) see different rows?

Comment: I've tried and failed to find the answer in the [official dox](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/index.html). A "read the dox" answer is totally valid- as long as you include a link for me to read. Thank you!

Comment: It only runs the last Select statement, since you don't actually use CTE in this query.

Comment: I guess I will have to update my "trivial" example then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here [WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH):

> The primary query and the WITH queries are all (notionally) executed at the same time. This implies that the effects of a data-modifying statement in WITH cannot be seen from other parts of the query, other than by reading its RETURNING output. If two such data-modifying statements attempt to modify the same row, the results are unspecified.

If you want more detailed information the see [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html). In this section it runs through a variety of scenerios.

Comment: I think this pretty much settles it. I definitely didn't read this far, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All three scans are performed with the snapshot of the query, so they are all guaranteed to see the same statenof the database.

Answer (score 0):

EXPLAIN ANALYSE applied to your example provides something like :

```
Seq Scan on t1 (cost=0.00..71.21 rows=621 width=233) (actual time=0.015..0.102 rows=621 loops=1)"
Planning Time: 0.078 ms
Execution Time: 0.132 ms
```

which confirms @Anton Grig comment.